# Deploying SSRS reports on a different server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012

We have SQL Server 2012 database (Enterprise Edition) and we want to start using SSRS.   We would like to deploy the SSRS reports on a different server so we don’t have users going to the database server to run their reports.  I know this is possible but I have a few questions on how to set it up.

1. On the server where we want to deploy the reports to (the report server), can we run SQL Server with Reporting Services installed and have them point back to the database server where the data is stored?
2. If we do that, can we run SQL Server Express on the report server?
3. How do we tell the report server to point back to the database server to get to the data?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In a report you can point to a data source that (as long as it
 has permission) can read from any SQL Server Instance/Database combination. You have to change the data source of each report or if its a shared data source you only have to change it once.

If you are using SQL Server Express, the database(s) used by SSRS must be on the same box that SQL Server Express is but the data that the report(s) use can be anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is very helpful.